# AWS AppSync add multiple children into one parent attribute when creating new item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

I have a question of AWS AppSync. I wonder whether there is a way to add multiple children under one parent attribute when creating new Item.

I have a table called `content_table` and table has attribute called `countries`. When user add new content for the table user can select multiple countries under one content.

I want to know how I set AppSync and resolver to accomplish above task?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to store my countries as array of string. This is how I set schema and resolver in AWS AppSync.

schema:

```
 type Content {
    contentId: ID!
    countries: [String]
  }
```

resolver:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "PutItem",
    "key" : {
        "contentId" : { "S" : "${context.arguments.contentId}" }
    },
    "attributeValues" : {
        "trending" :{ "SS" :[
                      #foreach($item in ${context.arguments.countries})
                          "${item}",
                      #end
                     ]},
               }
}
```

It was successful and here is my daynamodb look after add new content. [Dynamodb table for store content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vhg7.png)